# Is Azure DevOps a PaaS or IaaS?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, saas, paas, iaas

This is regarding Microsoft's Azure DevOps(Formerly VSTS). Just wanted to clear things, can Azure DevOps be classified as a Platform as a Service. Since it is a cloud service it should be categorized into IaaS but it eliminates the middleware/OS in pipeline. If not then where does it go in the cloud services area? IaaS/SAAS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure DevOps is SaaS for end users (Developers,PM,QA and other stakeholder). In the backend, all the services offer by "Azure DevOps" may run on VMs or Physical server. That mean Microsoft point of view, they may use combination of IaaS & PaaS solution for this platform. Ultimately all services running on VM or physical server.

Answer (score 2):

Its a SaaS, since you are buying a service, not a platform, not virtual machines.

Comment: But what about the part where we store, build and deploy our application source code in it. We use their service but have our code going into pipeline.

Comment: so? you dont have to manage anything in vsts, its a collection of services. obviously to use services you need to input something to them? with that kind of logic outlook.com is PaaS as well.

Comment: So !! Azure Devops is like a virtual storage. Every computing happens on cloud. With this in mind IAAS is the category for this since it involves cloud computing, and development and deployment of PaaS, SaaS & Web scale applications.

Comment: ok, at this point it probably makes no sense to respond anything else

Answer (score 0):

From [learn.microsoft.com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/data-protection?view=azure-devops)

> Based on the on-premises capabilities, with additional cloud services, we manage your source code, work items, builds, and tests. Azure DevOps uses platform as a service (PaaS) infrastructure and many Azure services, including Azure SQL, to deliver a reliable, globally available service for your development projects.

So according to Microsoft it is PaaS.